# Revoking Amazon S3 Bucket or Object Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I see from the [PUT Bucket acl - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTacl.html) documentation how one would go about applying an ACL to a bucket AND also to any objects within that bucket ([PUT Object acl - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUTacl.html)).

The documentation isn't clear on how one would go about revoking permissions that have been applied previously, though.  The `Permission` object in the `Grant` object doesn't seem to have values other than `READ`, `READ_ACP`, `WRITE`, `WRITE_ACP`, and `FULL_CONTROL`.

I also checked [Managing ACLs Using the REST API - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-using-rest-api.html) in the S3 Developer Guide and it isn't clear on this matter from what I can see.

Is there a way through the S3 API to delete permissions for a specific user?

Comment: The documentation links you provided talk about applying permissions on a bucket and an object. They are _not_ related to granting permissions to specific users. Could you please clarify what you are seeking?

Comment: Yes, the permission is applied to a grantee, which can be a user or a group.  Granting a permission to a grantee that is a canonical user (by ID or email) absolutely adjusts what level of access they have to the bucket as a whole or specific objects.  ```emailAddress — if value specified is the email address of an AWS account```, ```id — if value specified is the canonical User ID of an AWS account```, ```uri — if granting permission to a predefined Amazon S3 group```. I see APIs for PUT and GET but no way to change or delete them once they have been written.

Comment: From the developer guide: ```Amazon S3 access control lists (ACLs) enable you to manage access to buckets and objects. Each bucket and object has an ACL attached to it as a subresource. It defines which AWS accounts or groups are granted access and the type of access.``` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lakeformation/revoke-permissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that PUTting a new `AccessControlPolicy` deletes the one that was already in place, so to remove permissions, perform another PUT with the full `AccessControlPolicy`, less the one you wish to remove.